# Network drive vs Favourite in accessing a shared folder in Windows desktop

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, shared-folders, favorites

I have a shared folder in a windows desktop running windows 7, and this has a limitation of allowing only 20 concurrent users. If my team maps this folder as a "network drive" in their desktop (rather than saving the link as a "windows favorite"), would that mean they eat into number of concurrent users limit even if they are just logged on to their desktops and not actually accessing/working on the shared folder?

The problem is, my team size is 25 and all should have access this shared folder (but not all the time). Some map it as network drive and some map it as favorite. At times when someone is trying to access this shared folder, it says "number of maximum connections exceeded" but some other times it goes through fine. I am sure 20 of them are NOT working on that shared folder at the same time. So trying to check if  mapping it as "network drive" reduces the number of concurrent users available? and can it be avoided by saving the link as a favorite?

PS: I found similar question in [Why is it bad to map network drives in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/393397/why-is-it-bad-to-map-network-drives-in-windows?newreg=3041c04786e547e9b73988fd42585f2f) but the responses doesnt really answer my ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that mapping a drive letter to a share will (most times*) create a connection and hence use one of your concurrent connections. *If the user has gone in to mapped drive during that logged in session or a file has been read by a program.

In other words if you map a drive, then reboot and do not open the drive whatsoever it *should* sit without making a connection, however if anything triggers the drive mapping to be 'activated' then it will create a session on the computer that is sharing the folder.

If you load control panel and then administrative tools, go into computer management. Then on the left drill down to shared folders and check in sessions, you can see from here what sessions are being used these can then be cross referenced to the open files list below and if a user has a session but no open files then most likely its the mapped drive holding that session open.

Hope this helps happy to assist more just comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesH. I tested the scenarios while monitoring the sessions in computer management. When someone maps it as a network drive, even after they close the files and folders that are being accessed from the shared folder, the session continue to stay-on. But when someone saves the link as favorite, after they close all the files and folders from shared folder, the session is closed. So i think in this sense, it is beneficial to ask my team not to map it as a network drive and save it only as a favorite.

Comment: Glad I could help Sathya