# What are the benefits of Windows "Map Network Drive"?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, smb

Windows Explorer offers to map SMB paths to a drive letter, i.e. right-click on `\\some-computer\some-share`, and select *Map network drive...*, choose a drive letter.

[image]

#### Does a "mapped network drive" offer any benefits?

For example, is there underlying caching that improves performance?  Does it enable some useful SMB protocol feature like *SMB Direct*?

This question is ***not about the immediately obvious benefits*** like the user does not have to remember credentials, or remember an SMB path, or *Reconnect as sign-in* option within the *Map Network Drive* wizard.  This question is about underlying technical differences.

Comment: So you want to know what the fundamental differences are for using a mapped network drive rather than UNC path using the same SMB share but that's mounted to a Windows drive letter, right? I know there are some apps that won't work with a UNC for example so that's another not too obvious benefit, for application compatibility purposes. I assume you are not asking why use an SMB share rather than a local file system here too, just what those levels of non-obvious benefits are to using a mapped drive rather than just using the UNC path i.e. `\\servername\sharename`

Comment: Check if this article was helpful to you: [The Magic of Drive Mapping](https://www.itprotoday.com/strategy/magic-drive-mapping)

Comment: Mapped drives were invented by a programmer who pondered how to make a network  resources available in MS-Dos 3.1 (there is device names like printers use or mounting into a directory as two alternatives). There were superseded by UNC paths about 30 years ago but most programs couldn't handle them at the time. So admins kept mapping drives.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/393397/is-it-bad-to-map-network-drives-in-windows .

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the default setting to reconnect or check the box (if it had been cleared), then “persistence” has been turned ON and the drive will reconnect at login.

I find mapped drives like this are more reliable than browsed connections, so I use the mapped drive approach.

Those are the main two benefits.

This method compared to other methods does not improve performance significantly, although performance of mapped drives is very good. This is what I have observed. Mapped drives are about as good as it gets.

Also, whether I use my computer at clients or in my home office, mapped drives go as fast as the network in the place allows. So I am not convinced mapped drives "cache" anything that would speed things up or hinder things.  Remember that network connections are all different.

Comment: I've also observed that Mapped Drive performance is consistently faster.  This is one reason for the question; Network Mapped Drives appear much faster than plain SMB paths, so I'd guess Windows is caching more than just the username and password (or perhaps enabling an SMB feature like _SMB Direct_).  Unfortunately Microsoft does not publish any information describing technical implementation of Network Drive Mapping.

Comment: As I mentioned in my Answer, Mapped Drives are very fast (I would say about as fast as you can get). But browsed connections on my other laptop are also fast. So some of the variations may depend on the network connection. But mapped drives are as good as it gets.

Comment: I also amended my answer to indicate that location does not matter (taking network differences into account) so I do not believe there is caching that helps or hinders connections (because the locations are different infrastructures).

Answer (score 0):

Mapped drives let users easily and quickly navigate a network.

Using mapped drives, click to access network resources, if you work in Windows Explorer, My Computer, or software application dialog boxes such as Open or Save.

Drive mapping is a feature of some operating systems, including Microsoft Windows, that allows the user to assign a standard local drive volume letter (like C:\ or D:) to a drive on a remote machine connected to the user's computer over a network. Mapping a drive has several benefits.

Comment: The OP is specifically asking what the benefits are. You have only mentioned one yet you later state there are "several". Can you expand upon these?